# Default value for DATETIME field

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a .mwb file that I want to forward engineer. It contains the query creating new table, which in turn creates a column with DATETIME type.

The part of this query that throws an error is:

```
'last_send_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

The error is:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1067: Invalid default value for 'last_send_at'
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`DATETIME` fields must be left either with a `null` default value, or no default value at all.

> For date and time types other than TIMESTAMP, the default is the appropriate “zero” value for the type. For the first TIMESTAMP column in a table, the default value is the current date and time.

[Check it here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using pretty old version of mysql where the default values are not allowed for `datetime`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Here are the fiddles for mysql 5.5 and 5.6 and in both it works

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b6fa

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b6fab